# How to unlock a disk during installation?

Tags: system-installation, encryption

I'm installing elementary OS for the first time. I'm using a MacBook 2008 unibody which had El Capitan as the OS. Installation was proceeding satisfactorily until I got this message: "Please unlock disk sda3_crypt"
What does this mean and how do I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

The question was solved by the original poster. I'm moving that content to an answer, to properly match the Q&A model:

> I've got it sorted. I just had to use the security password I entered on setup.

Comment: @Paul, please set this answer as accepted (or write another one, if you prefer the self-answer method), so that the system can mark this question as solved.